# Java compilation error : /bin/ld:cannot find -ljvm

Tags: java, linux, gcc, java-native-interface, fuse

I am trying to build a java project  http://sourceforge.net/projects/fuse-j/?source=typ_redirect on fedora machine. The compilation fails while compiling JNI bindings.

MakeFile

```
include ../build.conf
include ../jvm_ldpath.def

SRCS := javafs.c javafs_bindings.c
HDRS := javafs.h javafs_bindings.h
LIB_SO := libjavafs.so

INCLUDES := -I${FUSE_HOME}/include -I${JDK_HOME}/include    -I${JDK_HOME}/include/linux

LDPATH := ${LDPATH} -L${FUSE_HOME}/lib


all: ${LIB_SO}

${LIB_SO}: ${SRCS} ${HDRS}
gcc -fPIC -shared -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -o ${LIB_SO} ${INCLUDES} ${LDPATH}   -ljvm -lfuse -lpthread ${SRCS}

clean:
   rm -f ${LIB_SO}
```

Error:

```
/bin/ld: cannot find -ljvm
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:17: recipe for target 'libjavafs.so' failed
make[1]: *** [libjavafs.so] Error
```

JDK_HOME ,FUSE_HOME are correctly set. Can you suggest what can be wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The jvm shared library will be found in a path under `$JDK_HOME`, however, you are not adding that path to your `LDPATH` make variable.  You need to add `-L${JDK_HOME}/lib` to `LDPATH` (or wherever `libjvm.so` is found).